# Could someone explain this katakana reading of ＜光る葉っぱ＞ from 鹿の王?

Tags: readings, katakana, creative-furigana

In the first page of the novel Shika no Ou by Uehashi Nahoko, this proper noun/kanji is used with some unusual furigana: <光る葉っぱ> read as ピカ・パル.
Since it's a fantasy novel and I know that the author uses non-Japanese derived names in her work, I figured it may be the case here. But, it's my first time reading one of her books and I'm generally confused if this is a given name, a plant name, or something else. How would a Japanese reader interpret this?

[image: shikanooupg1]

Comment: It is listed under plants [here](https://researchmap.jp/blogs/blog_entries/view/87854/91972aa65f6260fc81293bda484f8f6e?frame_id=391292).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is very common in novels and lyrics, and similar questions have been asked many times:

- [Why is 未来 read as あした?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29431/5010)
- [Why are some lyrics' words written in kanji whose usual reading is not how it is sung?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/5010)
- [Why do some kanji have furigana that are not valid readings?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5565/5010)
- [Are these furigana wrong?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66762/5010)
- [Reading 男 or 女 as ひと](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1448/5010)

In your case, the author want you to read this word as ピカ・バル, but also want you to know the meaning of ピカ・バル is "shining leaf".