# Are these furigana wrong?

Tags: furigana, creative-furigana

[image]

Looking up the words, I get [日本]{にほん} and [異世界]{いせかい} but don't get anything matching こつち or むこう. Is the furigana used here wrong?

Comment: FYI, the furigana on 異世界 is こっち, not こつち. It's common in furigana to not show a size difference with the typically smaller characters.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/14544 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14308/14544

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the furigana do not show the normal readings of the kanji.

No, the furigana are not wrong.

Kanji and furigana combinations are sometimes used to provide a multi-layered reading experience, where one provides the meaning and the other provides the dialog as spoken by the characters.  Doing this provides more context and specificity than is possible in pretty much any other written language.

*(This basic issue has been brought up before, and this thread will likely be closed as a duplicate.  Please see the other threads linked in the comments for further details.)*

Comment: Could you explain for the example what extra context is for こつち or むこう

Comment: @M---: The furigana here indicate what the speaker actually says: こっち ("this way, here, over here"), while the kanji indicate what the speaker means: 異世界 ("another world, the other side, etc.").  Likewise for むこう ("over there, across the way, etc."), where the kanji show that the speaker means 日本 ("Japan").