# Why is 野良 read as ぼく in this song?

Tags: readings, song-lyrics, creative-furigana

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to link to the song but the title is 『この街に晴れはこない』 by 美波

Lyrics:

> 同じ温度を探すよ
>
> 結局のところ
>
> 野良{ぼく}たちどこにもいられないや

After doing a bit of research it seems to be an 当て字 reading which can either mean a field or a stray and it seems to be the latter in this case. The part that confuses me is that it's read as「のら」.
Is this a literary thing where the writer chose to use certain kanji just to specify the meaning?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14308  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29431  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5565

Comment: I'm pretty sure the artist just styled it that way because the sentence it is in means "We don't belong anywhere," meaning that they are 'stray' like 野良 actually means.

Comment: If you're asking how the author can conveniently specify a hiragana for a kanji, Eddie Kal's links should help. If you're asking the legitimacy of this specific lyric where ぼく is linked with 野良, then it's subjective/opinionated. I do think StandAlone2323's assessment is probably spot on. But on the contrary to the composer complaining "we have no place to blend in", the reality is this kind of emo lyric is so typical and cliché that it's actually far from being a "stray dog". More like mass-produced chickens from a giant farm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some lyrics' words written in kanji whose usual reading is not how it is sung?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/198/why-are-some-lyrics-words-written-in-kanji-whose-usual-reading-is-not-how-it-is) See also this tag info: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags/creative-furigana/info