# Why does this kanji use "sora" as its reading?

Tags: kanji, readings

There's a song called 碧羅の天へ誘えど and it's read as "Hekira no Sora e Izanaedo". Is "Sora" another reading for 天？　I don't see it listed on Jisho.org, and 天 seems to almost always use "Ten" as its reading.

Comment: See here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/198/why-are-some-lyrics-words-written-in-kanji-whose-usual-reading-is-not-how-it-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reading of そら is a nonstandard reading found almost exclusively in crative writings such as lyrics and novel titles. It's in the same vein as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/5010). Using a nonstandard reading is a common way to make the name sound more interesting in Japanese.

In person names, there are a few people named 天【そら】 (including [this seiyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sora_Amamiya)), but I think it tends to be used as a little peculiar stage name.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Wikipedia says "Sora" is a Nanori reading for 天, which is apparently used for names and places