# What is the definition of 凶々?

Tags: adjectives

I tried searching on Jisho for the following kanji (凶々) as written in the book, but nothing shows up, even after I type in only the ruby script (magamaga), none of the kanji match what is in the book.

> 手には、**凶々{まがまが}しく**光るナイフではなく、　ボアのついた防寒服を抱えている。

Answer (score 4):

凶々しい is [another](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%87%B6%E3%80%85%E3%81%97%E3%81%84) way of writing [禍々しい](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%87%B6%E3%80%85%E3%81%97%E3%81%84).

Comment: Are there any nuances or differences between the two manners of writing that would affects the meaning?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey I can't find any real meaningful differences between the usages: (see for example: https://books.google.com/books?id=fCkzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT209&lpg=PT209&dq="凶々しい"), so I can only speculate that the difference is due to usage #'s or is the difference between the kanjis  凶 (bad luck leading to bad things happening) and 禍 (unexpected bad things happening)

Comment: That「凶」is the one from 「凶器」(murder weapon) and definitely has a greater physical immediacy to it. You can see it more clearly in the traditional version of the same character「兇」which is made from「兄」- pictorially ominous, don't you think?

Comment: This word is normally written 禍々しい. I cannot read 凶々しい without furigana (although I may be able to guess). It's almost like a ["creative ateji"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/198/5010) to me.

Comment: @naruto I tried clicking the link, but I still don't really know what the term "ateji" means in the context of the link? Does "creative ateji" mean 'a different kanji to be more specific with the meaning the singer/writer is attempting to convey across'?

Comment: @Toyu_Frey Well, "creative jukujikun" should be the technically better way to put this... Anyway, many novelists and lyricists like to use nonstandard kanji not taught at school, believing it looks cool. When you see furigana, or when you see a word your IME doesn't recognize, you have to consider this possibility.